# Is it possible to create a monoid instance for a GADT?

Tags: haskell, gadt

Given the following data type

```haskell
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data Response a where
  ResponseMap :: HashMap Text (Sum Int) -> Response (HashMap Text (Sum Int))
  ResponseSum :: Sum Int -> Response (Sum Int)
```

how would I derive a monoid instance for it? For the definition of `mappend` I can pattern match on the constructors

```haskell
  (ResponseSum v1) `mappend` (ResponseSum v2) = undefined
  (ResponseMap v1) `mappend` (ResponseMap v2) = undefined
```

and combine the values easily but I don't see how I would implement `mempty`, or if it's indeed possible, or makes sense?

Comment: Your GADT isn't really a GADT. It's just like `newtype Response a = Response a` but not as useful because `a` can only be `Sum Int` or `HashMap Text (Sum Int)`. If you use a `newtype` you can use `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` to get the `Monoid` instance for free

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson if I were to define `Response a` as a newtype would I have a way to define a function over it that knows what `a` it's working with?

Comment: I'm fond of the old-fashioned way `f :: Response (Sum Int) -> Foo`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you've noticed, you can't provide an `instance Monoid (Response a)`, because you can't define `mempty :: Response a`.  Why not?  Well, `mempty` has to have type `Response a` for *all* `a`, including, say, `Bool`.  But you can't construct a value of type `Response Bool`, only `Response (HashMap Text (Sum Int))` and `Response (Sum Int)`.  So you won't be able to create a `mempty`.  This isn't a problem for `mappend`, because you're *given* a `Response a`, so you can check which `a` you were given.  But `mempty` has nothing to analyze.

So what can you do?  Well, first of all, you can provide an `instance Semigroup (Response a)`.  A semigroup is exactly a monoid without `mempty`, so this is exactly what you want.  As of GHC 8, you can find this type class in the `base` package, in the module [`Data.Semigroup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html); prior to that, you need to use the [`semigroups`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroups) package, with the same module name.  Instead of `mappend`, it uses the binary operator `(<>)`.  So you'd have

```
import Data.Semigroup
import Data.Monoid hiding ((<>))

-- ...

instance Semigroup (Response a) where
  ResponseMap v1 <> ResponseMap v2 = ResponseMap $ v1 <> v2
  ResponseSum v1 <> ResponseSum v2 = ResponseSum $ v1 <> v2
```

You can also provide *specific* `Monoid` instances for the type indices that you can construct.  With `FlexibleInstances`, that looks like

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

instance Monoid (Response (HashMap Text (Sum Int))) where
  mempty = ResponseMap mempty
  mappend = (<>)

instance Monoid (Response (Sum Int)) where
  mempty = ResponseSum mempty
  mappend = (<>)
```

Now, for the cases where you *do* know what the unit is, you have a `Monoid` instance.